# Apollo Server Lambda slow performances

Tags: aws-lambda, apollo, apollo-server

I'm using Apollo Server Lambda to create some APIs hosted on AWS API Gateway and AWS Lambda. But what I noticed is that performances are really slow when the result has many fields. What I do is a query to get some documents from MongoDB, the query itself takes around 200ms to execute, however the response from the Graph server comes after 2 seconds! Is there something I can configure in the apollo server to optimize this? This is how I configured the apollo server

```
const app = new ApolloServer({
  schema: Schema,
  introspection: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" || true,
  playground: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" || true,
  context: async ({ context }) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    var dataloaderFactory = new MongooseDataloaderFactory();
    return { ...context, dataloaderFactory };
  },
  persistedQueries: {
    cache: new DynamoDBCache(dynamoDBClient, {
      tableName: process.env.CLIENT + "-" + process.env.NODE_ENV + "-Cache",
      partitionKeyName: "Hash",
      valueAttribute: "Query",
      ttlAttribute: "TTL",
      defaultTTL: 300
    })
  },
  dataSources: () => ({
    data: new Data()
  })
});
```

Comment: Do you know if the AWS Resources region is set to somewhere close to you? I know that for many resources and frameworks, the default region is us-east-1 (N. Virginia) and can be configured in the deployment step.

Comment: Is this the lambda cold start?

Comment: The deployment region is eu-central-1, which should be the closest region near to my location (Italy). And no, is not the lambda cold start, since if I repeat the query multiple times the time to return to client is always high (although of course being lower than the first try)

Comment: I think OP mentioned he is timing the query itself at ~200ms. I assume that he is timing that within the lambda call.